# Cannot run arquillian tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to use Arquillian for some unit tests, however I can't find why they fail when deployed using Maven.

This is the class test:

```
package com.ndeveloper.spec.test;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ArchivePaths;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.ByteArrayAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.ndeveloper.spec.controller.GreetingBean;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GreetingBeanTest {

@Inject
GreetingBean greetingBean;

@Deployment
public static JavaArchive createTestArchive()
{
    return ShrinkWrap.create( JavaArchive.class,"test.jar").
            addClass(GreetingBean.class).addAsManifestResource(
                    new ByteArrayAsset("<beans/>".getBytes()),
                    ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));

}

@Test
public void testInjection(){
    Assert.assertEquals("Hello World", greetingBean.getGreeting());     
}
}
```

And I'm using the jboss jboss-javaee6-webapp archetype. What's strange is that originally the test worked fine... However after using several times them. The following error started to appear:

**Tests in error:
com.ndeveloper.spec.test.GreetingBeanTest: Cannot obtain MBeanServerConnect to:               service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:1090/jmxrmi**

The surefire report says the following:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.ndeveloper.spec.test.GreetingBeanTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.309 sec <<< FAILURE!
com.ndeveloper.spec.test.GreetingBeanTest  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot obtain MBeanServerConnection to: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:1090/jmxrmi
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.MBeanServerConnectionProvider.getConnection(MBeanServerConnectionProvider.java:64)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.remote.RemoteDeployableContainer.getMBeanServerConnection(RemoteDeployableContainer.java:66)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.remote.RemoteDeployableContainer.startInternal(RemoteDeployableContainer.java:52)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.start(CommonDeployableContainer.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$5.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:144)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$5.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:134)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:182)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:133)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:83)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:76)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:175)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:68)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:76)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub:                              javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is               java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:338)
at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:248)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.MBeanServerConnectionProvider.getConnection(MBeanServerConnectionProvider.java:60)
... 69 more
    Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:101)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:185)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1886)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1856)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:257)
... 71 more
    Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:97)
... 76 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
at   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
... 81 more
```

And finally my arquillian.xml is configured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

<!-- Uncomment to have test archives exported to the file system for inspection -->
<!--    <engine>  -->
<!--       <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property>  -->
<!--    </engine> -->

<!-- Example configuration for a remote JBoss AS 7 instance -->
<container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
  <protocol type="jmx-as7">
     <property name="executionType">REMOTE</property>
  </protocol>
  <configuration>
     <property name="jbossHome">D:\JavaWindows\servers\jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final\jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final</property>
  </configuration>
</container>
```

However I can't figure out why does arqullian stopped running the tests. As I told you before, they used to work however after a settings change?? Idk.... this error started to appear.

Just in case the test were run with the following command:
**mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-remote**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute jbossHome in the arquillian.xml should be as:

D:\JavaWindows\servers\jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final\jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final

You should be add two slashes instead of one slash.

You shall verify if your jboss as 7 is running before the execution of tests. This is because you configured as REMOTE.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of container, i.e. JBoss 7 managed or remote, you need to have certain configurations set up correctly, in order to make Arquillian connect to the JBoss server.

In case of managed server you need to tell Arquillian where to find the JBoss. This could be done either by setting JBOSS_HOME as system properties, or add "jbossHome" configuration to arquillian.xml

In case of remote JBoss container, Arquillian needs 2 extra parameters:
managementAddress
managementPort,

Arquillian use default 127.0.0.1:9999. If your server is running on different host/port, then the 2 parameters should be configured in arquillian.xml

Under following link you will find sevreal running examples for Arquillian Test with JBoss 7 or JBoss 5:

http://milestonenext.blogspot.de/2012/12/ejb3-integration-test-with-arquillian.html