# Arquillian test execution fails with JBoss 7.1 and vanilla Jboss kitchensink example

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

Following the README instructions of the [jboss-as-kitchensink example](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Kitchensink+quickstart), I have tried to run the arquillian tests as advertised, with following results:

when running  `mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-remote`, I get these exceptions (copied from the surefire reports). Sorry for the long listing, I think the `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` exception near the bottom of the listing is the most relevant event but I'm not sure:

```
<error message="Could not deploy to container" type="org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException">org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Could not deploy to container
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:68)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.deploy(CommonDeployableContainer.java:142)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:156)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:123)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:266)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:79)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:258)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:234)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:182)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection failed
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:113)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentManager.executeOperation(ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentManager.java:47)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.AbstractServerDeploymentManager.execute(AbstractServerDeploymentManager.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.executeDeploymentPlan(ArchiveDeployer.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:58)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection failed
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolChannelClient.connectSync(ProtocolChannelClient.java:164)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementClientChannelStrategy$Establishing.getChannel(ManagementClientChannelStrategy.java:166)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:138)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$1.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:62)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:252)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:151)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:111)
    ... 98 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:701)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker$1.handleEvent(NioXnioWorker.java:322)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker$1.handleEvent(NioXnioWorker.java:318)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:72)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioHandle.run(NioHandle.java:90)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:184)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:268)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:250)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:359)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:347)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolChannelClient.connect(ProtocolChannelClient.java:125)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolChannelClient.connectSync(ProtocolChannelClient.java:134)
    ... 106 more
```

Have found nothing useful on that by googling or on the jboss forums. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341308/cannot-run-arquillian-tests) does not help.

My Jboss is running, I have the management-native port set to 9999 (the default), double-checked the `jbossHome` property in the arquillian.xml

When running `mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-managed`, the server starts up, deploys the application and then nothing happens...

What could be the source of the problems and what can be done? Any additional info I could provide?
Thank you

**EDIT**
Here are the relavant sections of the `pom`. Note - this is the unchanged pom from the kitchensink example. I have changed nothing.

dependency management:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee6.with.tools.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

arquilllian dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

the arquilllian remote profile (the managed profile is almost identical):

```
    <profile>
        <!-- We add the JBoss repository as we need the JBoss AS connectors for
            Arquillian -->
        <repositories>
            <!-- The JBoss Community public repository is a composite repository
                of several major repositories -->
            <!-- see http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users -->
            <repository>
                <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
                <name>JBoss Repository</name>
                <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                <!-- These optional flags are designed to speed up your builds by reducing
                    remote server calls -->
                <releases>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
                <name>JBoss Repository</name>
                <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                <releases>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>

        <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests in a remote
            JBoss AS instance -->
        <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-remote -->
        <id>arq-jbossas-remote</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
```

Comment: Please add to your question, the relevant section from your POM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging in the configs, I managed to solve the issue : I forgot about having modified the `standalone.xml` config, setting the socket offset from 0 to 100 to avoid port conflicts:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:100}">
```

The tests run now :)

What's funny is that the JBoss management console was totally oblivious to my config changes and just displayed the configurated defaults, so It didn't occur to me to look in the port config.

My bad, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your aquillian version. I remember a similar issue after upgrading from `jboss-as-7.1.0.CR1b` to `jboss-as-7.1.0.Final` and solved it by upgrading this dependency as well.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.CR7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

But I'm not sure if it's defined in `org.jboss.bom`, so give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, Thor. The arquillian versions are actually defined in the bom and the effective pom features the same 1.0.0.CR7 version as your example. I have switched through the 3 available milestones for the bom - from 1.0.0.M1 to ...M3 but they all feature the same arquillian version...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Thor.

It looks like a compitability problem between "aquillian core version" and "aqquillian jboss container version". With Arquillian evolving, sometimes it is not so easy to find which arquillian works with which container.

There are some working examples with correct combination of versions here, maybe it helps:
http://milestonenext.blogspot.de/2012/12/ejb3-integration-test-with-arquillian_17.html